# Force "Submit to review" when a post is updated

Tags: posts, users, review

I think that everything is in the title. I would like to find a way to change the status of a post to "pending" when the post is updated when the user is an "author". I already tried with differents plugin but none of them worked. I'm new to wordpress so i don't really understand how am i suppose to modify the code to get this feature.

Thx for your help !

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to **stop author to publish post**, and force him to **Submit For Preview**. Just add this code to your `functions.php` and you are all done.

```
<?php
   function take_away_publish_permissions() {
        $user = get_role('author');
        $user->add_cap('publish_posts',false);
   }
   add_action('init', 'take_away_publish_permissions' );
?>
```

** Updated Code ** 
*This code shared here is for setting post status to preview or pending whenever a author update a post.*

```
function postPending($post_ID)
 { 
     if(get_role('author'))
     {
        //Unhook this function
        remove_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);

        return wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_ID, 'post_status' => 'pending'));

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3 );
     }
 }
add_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);
```

**NOTE:** If you are calling a function such as wp_update_post that 
includes the save_post hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the 
function you need, then re-hook it afterward. For details look into this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: yeah that works but why to modify the default role. I would suggest to create a new user role with contributor capability to add/edit/update post.

Comment: It's possible that he need all other capabilities of an author, except this one.  Even, I don't know his original requirement. So, why to create a new Role and increase complexity. Modify the existing one.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same when the author want to update a post ?

Comment: (btw thx for your help)

Comment: @S.Ardant No, I dont think so it is possible. You can check the **Roles and Capabilities** of a user. https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: @Amit Ok thx i'll check. But i tried to set the post status to pending just after an update but it doesnt seems to work and i don't really understand why. This is my function i used:

Comment: function postPending() {
   $postid = $post->ID;
     wp_update_post(array(
         'ID'    =>  $postid,
         'post_status'   =>  'pending'));
   }
add_action('wp_update_post', 'postPending' );

Comment: @S.Ardant I have updated the answer. Look into it.

Comment: @Amit It works ! Thx for your help !

Comment: @S.Ardant Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The user with author role is somebody who can publish and manage their own posts. So you can't change 
the default capability of your author user to disable publish post. 
You can set all users (authors) to contributors. Then they can only write posts and manage their posts but not publish them.

For reference : [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)